# javascript firebase cloud function : How to fix require is not defined error

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to call firebase functions from client side using their
[tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#web_2) but I keep getting the error require is not defined. I understand require is used most for nodejs server side application but how can this be solved on the client side. There has to be a way If the firebase tutorial specified it.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

here is my main.js file

```js
  const firebase = require("firebase");
// Required for side-effects
  require("firebase/functions");
  
 
checkout()
function checkout(){


var randomNumber = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('randomNumber');
randomNumber({text: messageText}).then(function(result) {
  // Read result of the Cloud Function.
  var sanitizedMessage = result.data.text;
  console.log(sanitizedMessage)

}).catch(function(error) {
  // Getting the Error details.
  var code = error.code;
  var message = error.message;
  var details = error.details;

  console.log(message)
  // ...
})

}

main.html file
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body  >

<div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <h1>My First Bootstrap Page</h1>
  <p>Resize this responsive page to see the effect!</p> 
</div>
  
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.0.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.0.2/firebase-functions.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.0.2/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    <script type="text/javascript">
     var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "41414414I",
    authDomain: "414444.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://414144.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "414-c4cc",
    storageBucket: "4144-cc4cc.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "414542",
    appId: "1:41:web:31415425",
    measurementId: "G-542g542"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.analytics();
  // Initialize Cloud Functions through Firebase
    var functions = firebase.functions();
</script>

<script>
 

</script>

 
<script src="main.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

How can i fix the error require is not defined and call the firebase function from client side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've already added the Firebase scripts into your HTML, you don't need to use require to add them again.  On top of that, require only works in environments such as nodejs or module bundlers, which you are not using here.

Simply remove the requires and start using the Fireabse SDKs that have already been added.